# _tkinter.TclError: this isn't a Tk application in matplotlib bar graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a program that analyzes certain videos and assigns a "score" every second based on the contents of the video. I have an example of some of the raw data that the program churns out, (x in seconds, y in score).

```
0 0
1 27
2 48
3 78
4 92
5 72
```

etc etc. My goal is to create an animated graph that goes along with the video. For example, when 1 second of the video plays, point (1, 27) is plotted. When 2 seconds pass, point (2, 48) is plotted. I don't care about the merging of the video and animated graph for now; right now I only care about getting the graph to plot 1 bar every second.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 100)) #a 0 to 10 x axis and a 0 to 100 y
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    with open('E:\PYTHON\data.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
        y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]

    ax.bar(x,y, width=0.7)
    plt.show()
    plt.draw()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

However, this code ends up sending out all my data in one image, rather than an animation, and then gives me this error. I suppose the "sending out all my data in one image" part stems from me not utilizing "i" in my x and y values, but in all honesty, I have no idea how to implement "i" in my animation code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 388, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 228, in __call__
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1030, in _start
    self.event_source.add_callback(self._step)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_callback'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 26, in blit
    dataptr, colormode, bboxptr)
_tkinter.TclError: this isn't a Tk application

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 227, in resize
    self.draw()
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in draw
    tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 34, in blit
    dataptr, colormode, bboxptr)
_tkinter.TclError: this isn't a Tk application
```

Could anyone help me animate this bar graph?

Comment: Of course you eventually want to use different data for each animation frame. But that is unrelated to the error you get. Try to remove the two lines `plt.show()
    plt.draw()`. If that removes the error, you may edit your question and tell us what data the file you read in contains and how you want to use it in an animation.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happens with my code. I have the matplotlib GUI running in the main thread, and this uses TkAgg as its backend. In another thread, I have some a function that updates the GUI visual every so often. I get the error you described after I close the GUI window but the other thread is still running and makes a call to update the figure that is no longer there. I've found some other help with this, and maybe it will work for you. The first thing you can do is make sure matplotlib is using the TkAgg backend

`import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.get_backend())`

If not, you can follow instructions here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/785505/how-to-ensure-matplotlib-in-a-python-3-virtualenv-uses-the-tkagg-backend) that says how to make matplotlib use TkAgg.

I've still not solved my own problem yet, but hopefully this pushes you in the right direction.